# Need Help In Scaling Vertx Http Server

Tags: java, vert.x

I am new to Vertx and trying out few things to get the better understanding of the vertx. I have written an application and need some help in deploying the multiple instances of the same, I have pasted the code below can anyone let me know if this is correct and the right way of doing it. Thanks in advance.

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.BodyHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.CorsHandler;

import com.test.handler.ApiRequestHandler;
import com.test.handler.PushToRedisApiHandler;
import com.test.handler.RequestValidationHandler;
import com.test.utils.JedisLocalConnectionPool;
import com.test.utils.JedisMasterConnectionPool;

public class TestServer extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> future) {

        JedisLocalConnectionPool localJedisPool = new JedisLocalConnectionPool(
                config().getString("redis.local.host", "127.0.0.1"), config()
                        .getInteger("redis.port", 6379), config().getString(
                        "redis.password", ""));

        JedisMasterConnectionPool masterJedisPool = new JedisMasterConnectionPool(
                config().getString("redis.master.host", "127.0.0.1"), config()
                        .getInteger("redis.port", 6379), config().getString(
                        "redis.password", ""));

        EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.route().consumes("application/json");
        router.route().produces("application/json");
        router.route().handler(
                CorsHandler.create("*").allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST));
        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
        router.post("/api/process-api-request").handler(
                new ApiRequestHandler(eventBus, localJedisPool));


        PushToRedisApiHandler pushToRedisHandler = new PushToRedisApiHandler(
                masterJedisPool);
        RequestValidationHandler validationHandler = new RequestValidationHandler(
                localJedisPool, masterJedisPool);
        eventBus.consumer("push.to.redis", pushToRedisHandler);
        eventBus.consumer("push.to.redis", validationHandler);

   // for running multiple instances
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept)
                    .listen(config().getInteger("http.port", 80));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats wrong, you don't have to instantiate the http server inside the verticle multiple times. You have to instantiate the verticle itself multiple times.

You can start your verticle with the vertx binary or as fatjar (Here is an example https://github.com/floriankammermann/vertx-examples/tree/master/hello-world-java)

You can add this commandline parameter to deploy multiple instances: `--instances 2`

You can also deploy your verticle programatically and pass the number of instances. You find an example here: https://github.com/floriankammermann/vertx-examples/blob/master/verticle-instances/src/main/java/org/swisspush/vertx/examples/CryptoVerticleStarter.java